# Parallel processing with Pipe command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, parallel-processing

I'd like to parallel process the command that downloads a live stream.
So if it has 4 parts and the `PARTS` variable contains the number 4, it should open 4 new cmd windows and process the individual part.

After reading a lot about parallel processing I came to the following solution:

```
set /p URL=Enter video URL: 
set /p NAME=Enter video name: 
set /p PARTS=Enter Number of Parts: 

for /l %%x in (1, 1, %PARTS%) do (
   start cmd /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\Streamlink\bin\streamlink.exe" -O "%URL%/%%x" best | ffmpeg -y -i pipe:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -absf aac_adtstoasc "%NAME%p%%x.mp4"
)
```

There seems to be an issue with the `|` command though since this script would open windows that close right after start and the output of the piped command `ffmpeg -y -i pipe:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -absf aac_adtstoasc "%NAME%p%%x.mp4` would show in the initial cmd window that executed the script.

How can I change it so the whole command gets executed in the new window?

Comment: put another pair of quotes around the whole command line to be executed: `start cmd /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Streamlink\bin\streamlink.exe" -O "%URL%/%%x" best | ffmpeg -y -i pipe:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -absf aac_adtstoasc "%NAME%p%%x.mp4""`

Comment: This throws `"\Streamlink\bin\streamlink.exe" Can not be processed syntactically at this point.`

Comment: sorry - escape the closing `)`: `start cmd /C ""C:\Program Files (x86^)\Streamlink\bin\streamlink.exe" -O "%URL%/%%x" best | ffmpeg -y -i pipe:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -absf aac_adtstoasc "%NAME%p%%x.mp4""`

Comment: Seems to be almost working. When I insert a streaming url with parameters they get cut off after the first parameter. For example https://url.com?type=stream&id=12 would try to open https://url.com?type=stream, afterwards I get an error command "id" was not found

Comment: well, you have to escape the `&` too: [any of these charcters you should prefix with the escape character: & \ < > ^ |](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) (plus the `)`, because you are inside a code block)

Comment: Makes sense. Is it possible to automatically escape these strings for the variable?

Comment: uuhh there is no general rule - it all depends on the context (inside parantheses, inside quotes,...) You'd need a lot of code to do proper escaping. Might be an object for [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: It would be sufficient to escape all & characters in the url.

Answer (score 2):

To not let the pipe process the output of the `start` command, you need to escape it:

```cmd
start "" cmd /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\Streamlink\bin\streamlink.exe" -O "%URL%/%%x" best ^| ffmpeg -y -i pipe:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -absf aac_adtstoasc "%NAME%p%%x.mp4"
```

Since quotation is not modified this way, the used path and all variable parts still appear quoted to the calling `cmd` instance too, so no more additional escaping is required, unless these strings may contain quotation marks on their own, in which case I strongly recommend [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```cmd
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem // some other code...

set /P URL="Enter video URL: "
set /P NAME="Enter video name: "

rem // some other code...

start "" cmd /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\Streamlink\bin\streamlink.exe" -O "!URL!/%%x" best ^| ffmpeg -y -i pipe:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -absf aac_adtstoasc "!NAME!p%%x.mp4"

rem // some other code...

endlocal
```

The `""` behind the `start` command should be stated to provide a window title; otherwise an error could occur as the first quoted item was taken as the title rather than as part of the command line.

The above line still could cause problems, since the `cmd` instance executing the actual commands receives the already expanded values rather than the variable. So you might even need to do this:

```cmd
rem // Supposing delayed expansion is disabled in the hosting `cmd` instance:
start "" cmd /C /V "C:\Program Files (x86)\Streamlink\bin\streamlink.exe" -O "!URL!/%%x" best ^| ffmpeg -y -i pipe:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -absf aac_adtstoasc "!NAME!p%%x.mp4"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem // Supposing delayed expansion is enabled in the hosting `cmd` instance:
start "" cmd /C /V "C:\Program Files (x86)\Streamlink\bin\streamlink.exe" -O "^!URL^!/%%x" best ^| ffmpeg -y -i pipe:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -absf aac_adtstoasc "^!NAME^!p%%x.mp4"

endlocal
```

Note that the pipe `|` creates two more `cmd` instances one for either side, implicitly.